# Nodejs - MySQL : How to get a specific result back to nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

Say I have a query like below...

```
SELECT 
    Username AS name,
    Occupation AS occ,
    Hobby AS hob
FROM 
    mt_User
```

At my `Nodejs` segment, I have...

```
conn.getConnection(
    function (err, client) {
        if(err){
            console.log('Connection Error');
            throw err;
        }

        client.query(thatQueryAbove, function(err, rows){

            if(err){
                console.log('Query Error');
            }

            var Username = rows???????
            var Occupation = rows??????
            var Hobby = rows???????

           ....How exactly do I call back the data with the alias 
             defined in my query like 'name', 'occ' and 'hob'?

         });
    });
```

Can anyone lemme how to retrieve the data back using the alias of my `SELECT` statement in `Node.js`?

Thank you in advance guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard Node.js driver for mysql. The code to accomplish above will look like below

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'mysqluser',
  password : 'yourpass',
  database : 'dbname'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT Username AS name,Occupation AS occ,Hobby AS hob FROM mt_User', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  if(rows && rows.length>0)
     console.log(rows[0].name, rows[0].occ, rows[0].hob);
  else
     console.log('No Results Found!');
});
```